# Realm stops processing my code without crashes the app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

For some reason when I call `let realm = Realm()` it ***stops*** processing (doesn't crash)  my code. My app is still running, but the screen keep frozen.

When I try to open default.realm using realm browser app, it shows me:

[image]

Again, it doesn't crash my app. It is a kind of pause.

1. No braekepoints
2. I've already tried: cocoapods and xcode install
3. I've already tried run on simulator and device (iPad)
4. App already deleted
5. Project cleaned up
6. Derived data cleaned up

Comment: When the browser is closed, does xcode freeze?

Comment: No. I have installed Real in other project and it works like a charm, but in this specific project it "pauses" my project.

Comment: Ok, definitely a project specific issue. I noticed you opened up a github issue as well, I believe things will be handled there. Please send over the project when you get a chance